# Application attempting to hit master database instead of the default database in the connection string

Tags: sql-server, database, server, web-config, database-connection

We have an issue that we've been unable to resolve.  We have a console application that attempts to run a `truncate` statement on a specific table within our `Billers` database.  This works fine on most of the environments and the specific `web.config` transformation file works properly when it's run locally.  However, when attempting to run this application from the environment's web server, the application attempts to perform the `truncate` statement on the `master` database instead.  Naturally this returns an error as the application is unable to find the specific table that needs truncated within the `master` database.

Does anyone know why it's attempting to hit the `master` database rather than the `Billers` database?  As I said, the correct database is hit when the application is run locally.  It's only an issue when an attempt is made to run the application from the web server.

This is the web.Staging.config transformation being used:

```
<add name="Billers" connectionString="Data Source=Staging.OurOrganization.org;Initial Catalog=Billers; User Id=NotTheRealUser; Password=NotTheRealPassword;MultiSubnetFailover=true;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

This is the actual connection string on the server:

```
<add name="Billers" connectionString="Data Source=Staging.OurOrganization.org;Initial Catalog=Billers; User Id=NotTheRealUser; Password=NotTheRealPassword;MultiSubnetFailover=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Perhaps the server has trouble understanding your connection string because of software/provider differences. Check what you are using against e.g. this great site: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @PeterB I've attached the connection string used.

Comment: Is that the connection string on the web server, or is that the transform statement from your Web.Release.config?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Sorry...see the update.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the user in the connection string has permissions to use the database in question?  Because that would be my first guess at why it's not going into the database in the connection string.

Comment: Yes...we attempted a `truncate` locally and the user was able to perform it just fine.  Our DBA's confirmed that the user is NOT even attempting to access the correct table.  Instead, it's attempting to go straight to the `master` database.

Comment: Which is why I wondered whether the user - in production - had privileges to access anything but `master` - if the user doesn't have permissions to use that `initial catalog` then I think the connection would fail over to using `master`, provided the user has access to that database.